# Convert 3D scene to 2D view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

The situation is follow: there is a large 3D model of the system, obtained by conversion from 3DMax (xaml markup file size ove 50MB). To work with the model used Viewport3D. But I need to display only the front view. The main problem is the resource intensity of the resulting application.

Question: How to convert 3D scene to 2D view? Preferably without any appreciable loss of quality.

Comment: Do your 3D objects move dynamically? Do you need to modify the scene in real-time? Have you tried to run the application with this 50MB scene? What are the problems with it? Does it work fluently?

Comment: What you want to do is a projection. 
Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection, You have to write an algorithm, I think.

Comment: We have static scene, but dynamically reload some elements in real time, and yes, I try to run this application, it requires too much resources

Answer (score 0):

You can render the front view to an image using [RenderTargetBitmap.Render()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.render.aspx) . This could take some time, but when it's done, you can discard the 3D model and display the 2D image instead.

Comment: This method make image from our scene, but we have scene with many elements, and need to call this elements from other parts of code